# Вызов метода при любом взаимодействии с mapView (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, карты

Есть экран с картой, на котором отслеживается мое положение и за ним движется обзор, то есть работает         `self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`, но при любом взаимодействии с картой, например юзер начинает ее двигать, увеличивать, уменьшать, нужно вызвать  `stopUpdatingLocation()`, делал это через `gestureRecognizer`, но проблема в том, что при первом касании карта не активна, то есть отрабатывает жест, вызывает `stopUpdatingLocation()`, но жесты самой карты, такие как увеличить/уменьшить, перетащить, при этом же касании не работают, а работают уже при втором прикосновении, когда `stopUpdatingLocation()` отработал.

Вопрос: Как отследить любое взаимодействие с mapView, и выполнить действие `stopUpdatingLocation()` за одно прикосновение, как в навигаторах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из вариантов, может Вам подойдет (если конечно еще совпадает работа с позицией)

1 В классе делегат:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

2 заводите флаг, к примеру

```
var isTouched = false
```

3 Создаете `UIPanGestureRecognizer` и добавляете к карте:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(mapIteractionHandle(_:)))
    panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}
```

4 обязательно переопределяете функцию делегата:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

5 в `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` прописываете для карты:

```
if !isTouched {
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
}
```

6 обрабатываете нажатие:

```
func mapIteractionHandle(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch sender.state {
    case .began:
        isTouched = true
        //Можете добавить и stopUpdatingLocation, тогда не будет возвращаться карта на Вашу позицию когда отпустите палец
    case .ended:
        isTouched = false
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: дело в том, что эти два метода работают постоянно сами по себе, ведь у меня отслеживается моя локация и обновляется положение карты автоматически, как в навигаторе, и оно в них заходит само по себе  каждую секунду, а задача стоит так, что бы при взаимодействии пользователя с картой, можно было вызывать другие методы
[скрин](http://pixs.ru/showimage/SimulatorS_7190016_24666368.png) То есть юзер следит за собой на карте и тут решил подвигать/сменить масштаб - происходит `stopUpdatingLocation ` , после чего он нажимает на кнопку человечка справа и пошло снова отслеживание `startUpdatingLocation`

Comment: может у вас есть идеи как быть?

Comment: @pbogdanv не заметил сразу комментарий, обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо вам за участие в вопросе, попробовал ваш обновленный вариант, и вышел на проблему, которая была в вопросе изначально, сейчас выглядит все так:  1. Я еду в машине, метка со мной на карте - постоянно в центре, обзор карты соответсвенно движется. 2. я решил посмотреть на карте другое что-то, за видимыми пределами, и начинаю двигать пальцем карту, а она не движется, а когда отпускаю палец - заходит в `mapIteractionHandle`  и  останавливаю обновление stopUpdatingLocation. 3. А уже после первого прикосновения, делая второе - я могу двигать карту. Это должно работать с первым прикосновением

Comment: пишу дабы убедиться, что комментарий не прошел мимо Вас)

Comment: @pbogdanv видел, не мог добраться чтоб проверить. Посмотрите обновление в ответе, проверил вариант - пока держу палец,  делаю с картой что необходимо, когда отпускаю - возвращается на место. Ну и комментарий добавил.

Comment: [видеозапись работы карты](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5Zcd/fiJj462fY), на видео хорошо видно, что жест работает, но только тогда, когда не перемещается карта, то есть нужно дотронутся к карте попав в промежуток между сменой позиции обзора, иначе она не двигается. Получается жест не работает во время анимации карты

Comment: @pbogdanv действительно, увеличил дистанцию и вылезло такое. Без анимации mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false) не подходит?

Comment: Вот без нее работает как нужно! Спасибо за помощь! Просто, конечно хотелось бы анимацию сохранить, может есть еще варианты какие-то, если мы все попробовали, и вариантов нету, оставлю так..

Comment: @pbogdanv согласен, с анимацией намного приятнее. Но когда пробую остановить анимацию, то все-равно нужно 2 касание, хоть и перестает карта перемещаться.

Comment: Тогда остановимся на этом варианте, Спасибо за помощь!